# Optimal way to replace values in Array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, replace

I have an array that looks like this (the real one is much longer, with around 150 elements):

```
static const MyConfig m_Original[] =
{
    {0x01, 0x04, 0}, 
    {0x02, 0x0A, 0},
    {0x03, 0x54, 0}, 
    {0x01, 0x05, 0},
    {0xA1, 0xE5, 0}, 
    {0xA2, 0x6B, 0}, 
    {0xA3, 0x2B, 0}, 
    {0xA1, 0xE3, 0}, 
};
```

In certain cases I would like to use **almost** the same array, but with a couple changes.

So I did a "patch" array:

```
static const MyConfig m_Patch[] =
{
    {0x01, 0x0F, 0}, 
    {0x02, 0x0F, 0},
    {0xA1, 0xFF, 0}, 
};
```

Note that the it is the only second value of each element (the `value`) the one that changes.

So, I would like to replace those 3 (maybe more in real life) values from the original array. And! as you see, some value are repeated, all repetitions should be replaced.

The two immediate solutions are:

1. Just create a new array with the needed values (but then I'm allocating a big array that I will never use.
2. Write a `for` loop comparing each element of each array and replacing if exists, which doesn't seem elegant (maybe I'm wrong (?))

The question: is there an optimal way of achieving this?

So at the end I would like `m_Original` to look like:

```
    {0x01, 0x0F, 0}, => Replaced
    {0x02, 0x0F, 0}, => Replaced
    {0x03, 0x54, 0}, 
    {0x01, 0x0F, 0}, => Replaced
    {0xA1, 0xFF, 0}, => Replaced
    {0xA2, 0x6B, 0}, 
    {0xA3, 0x2B, 0}, 
    {0xA1, 0xFF, 0}, => Replaced
```

FYI:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t Addr;
    uint16_t Value;
    uint32_t time;
} MyConfig ;
```

**EDIT**: `m_Original` should not be sorted, its order is important

Comment: Firstly, "_elegant"_ is extremely subjective and solicits opinion-based answers that are off-topic here.  Secondly, your problem is not clear.  You've mentioned that _"some values are repeated"_ while listing whole structures.  To me, each struct is a single value, but based on your example it looks like you're only comparing the `Addr` when matching.  Is that the case?  A simple solution would be to index your "patch" array with something like `std::unordered_map<uint16_t, const MyConfig*>` and then use that in a loop.  This avoids needing to loop over every patch element for every candidate.

Comment: An alternative to the above is to ensure you always store your patch with the addresses in sorted order.  Then you can binary-search the array (using `std::lower_bound` for example) without needing to construct any index at runtime.

Comment: @paddy you're right I'm edditing the question to specify that i'ts about the addres.

Comment: @paddy about "elegant", true, maybe I'm looking for "optimal" (?)

Comment: Optimal is also subjective.  It could be optimal in terms of execution time, or memory use, or even optimal for somebody to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Can you use `std::unordered_map<uint16_t , MyConfig>`?

Comment: How are you using that array in the end? Is there a reason of not using map with "Addr" as a key and {Value; Time} pair as value?

Comment: @JustShadow I think the original code is just old and no "cool"  oontainer was used, Just!  the "Addr" can be repeated, so it wouldn't work as a key (or would it? )

Comment: @Ivan [`unordered_multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) could work if the order weren't important.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you do not want to use a std::map or std::vector? However [this](https://godbolt.org/z/MxT51q69d) is a possible solution with vector. It can be modified to use std::array if you like:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

namespace { // Prefer anonymous namespaces before static

struct MyConfig // Use c++ syntax
{
    uint16_t Addr;
    uint16_t Value;
    uint32_t time;
};

const std::vector<MyConfig> m_Original =
{
    {0x01, 0x04, 0}, 
    {0x02, 0x0A, 0},
    {0x03, 0x54, 0}, 
    {0x01, 0x05, 0},
    {0xA1, 0xE5, 0}, 
    {0xA2, 0x6B, 0}, 
    {0xA3, 0x2B, 0}, 
    {0xA1, 0xE3, 0}, 
};

const std::vector<MyConfig> m_Patch =
{
    {0x01, 0x0F, 0}, 
    {0x02, 0x0F, 0},
    {0xA1, 0xFF, 0}, 
};

auto patch (std::vector<MyConfig> array,
            const std::vector<MyConfig> &patch) -> std::vector<MyConfig> {
    for (auto &o: array) {
        for (const auto & p: patch) {
            if (o.Addr == p.Addr) {
                // Replace values with the same address
                o = p;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}

} // namespace

int main() {
    auto patched = patch(m_Original, m_Patch);

    for (auto values: patched) {
        std::cout << std::hex << values.Addr << ", " << values.Value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Resulting output:

```
1, f
2, f
3, 54
1, f
a1, ff
a2, 6b
a3, 2b
a1, ff
```

If you want to change your original array (you dont, this is really bad practice) you do like this

```cpp
    const_cast<std::vector<MyConfig>&>(m_Original) = patch(m_Original, m_Patch);
```

If you want to unnest the loop and obfuscate it a bit, you can define some more functions like this (also not recommended)

```cpp
auto patch (std::vector<MyConfig> array,
            const std::vector<MyConfig> &patch) -> std::vector<MyConfig> {

    auto replace_if_in_patch = [&patch] (auto &value) {
        for (auto &p: patch) {
            if (value.Addr == p.Addr) {
                value = p;
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    for (auto &o: array) {
        replace_if_in_patch(o);
    }

    return array;
}
```

If you want a patch function that patches the incoming array, you might want to use references in the arguments

```cpp
void patch (std::vector<MyConfig> array&,
    // Notice change here -------------^
            const std::vector<MyConfig> &patch) -> std::vector<MyConfig> {
    for (auto &o: array) {
    //...
    // then remove the return statement
```

Comment: If `m_Original` can be sorted, you may consider binary search. (`std::lower_bound`)

Comment: It cannot be sorted @AyxanHaqverdili , just sis an edit for clarity

Comment: Tihs looks good :) , just 2 things: 1. I wanted toavoid the nested loop and 2. the goal is to change the actual value of `m_Original `

Comment: @Ivan you can't change value of a const variable...

Comment: @Ivan You somtimes can change values of const values, but you probably should not. 2: When you say you do not want a nested loop, do you mean that you want to hide the nested loop in a function? You need to nest the loop to do this in some way.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili ops! true

Comment: @Lasersköld I was wondering if I could just not use the nested loop at all. I thought on this becasue if `patch` has more elements , the execution amound of intructions will increase a lot

Comment: @Ivan If you want to avoid the nested for loop, you could use an `std::unsorted_map` using `Addr` as key instead of a `std::vector` for the patch.

Comment: @Ivan Like Jabberwrocky writes. Depending on your container you can get it as compact as you like, but from the question it seemes like you want a unordered vector of structs. And in that case nesting is the way to go.

Comment: @Ivan Added examples how to do what you asking for. But please don't do it ;)

Comment: `std::replace` will be your friend